# Django Inlineformset not working

Tags: django

I'm new to Django, so thanks in advance for your patience. I'm trying to use an inlineformset exactly as is outlined here:
http://charlesleifer.com/blog/djangos-inlineformsetfactory-and-you/
 The problem is, I'm getting an error like "'ingredient_formset' referenced before assignment". I see how this makes sense, in the case of a submitted, invalid form, but I don't know how to address it so that the user goes back to the form with the entered values.

Could you offer any advice about how to address the error? I know the original post is dated. Is there a more current approach I should try? Many thanks, Carrie

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code from the link you posted, I can see that the ingredient_formset variable is defined in all circumstances.

Perhaps you made a mistake with indentation and the main else code block applies to the `if form.is_valid()` rather than the `if request.POST` condition?

EDIT: here's a better and working version of the same code

```
def submit_recipe(request):
    form = UserSubmittedRecipeForm()
    ingredient_formset = IngredientFormSet(instance=Recipe())

    if request.POST:
        form = UserSubmittedRecipeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            recipe = form.save(commit=False)
            ingredient_formset = IngredientFormSet(request.POST, instance=recipe)
            if ingredient_formset.is_valid():
                recipe.save()
                ingredient_formset.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('recipes_submit_posted'))
    return render_to_response("recipes/submit.html", {
        "form": form,
        "ingredient_formset": ingredient_formset,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Thank you. I've double checked and the main else code block in my code does apply to the if request.POST (as far as I can tell). I'm having trouble getting a local copy of my code from the remote Unix server, otherwise I'd post it. Still, it looks to me like if the request is a POST, but the "if form.is_valid()" statement fails, then ingredient_formset is never defined. Wouldn't the code jump from the "if form.is_valid()" (assuming it fails) right to the return statement? I think I might try retyping the fn to double check the indentation.

Comment: Thank you! This gets me past this particular hurdle. :) Now the user is directed back to the form when is_valid fails, however, the ingredient_formset fields are reset and lose the previously entered data. ('form' fields do display the previously entered data as expected) The cause seems related to my original issue: if the code fails on 'if form.is_valid()', it jumps to the return statement, and ingredient_formset does not contain the data from request.POST. I still need to get that POST data into the formset even if 'form' is not valid...